# nginx reverse_proxy with axis camera - default rewrite not working

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I've got an AXIS camera sitting behind my firewall.

If you cURL to the camera's IP, it wants to redirect you to /view/index.shtml via a meta refresh.

I'm trying to access the camera via webserver-IP/camera.  My nginx config is simple - it looks like this:

```
    location /camera {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.205:80/;
            proxy_redirect default;
    }
```

This however is not working - the redirect isn't happening.  When I access webserver-IP/camera, it redirects me to webserver-IP/view  instead of webserver-IP/camera/view.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `proxy_redirect` with this line

```
proxy_redirect http://192.168.0.205:80/; http://192.168.0.205:80/camera/;
```

I don't know what your `Location` header says exactly, but you should get the idea, replace the IP with a hostname or whatever the redirect is trying to take you, you're simply telling nginx to append `/camera` to whatever redirect the website asks you to do

Comment: Tried this- The rewrite still doesn't seem to be happening.  When I curl /camera, this is what is being received: <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=/view/index.shtml">

Comment: Did you figure this out? Looking for the same without much luck

Comment: David, no, I did not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the html, js, and css returned by the axis camera all assumes that you are accessing it from a URL like `http://192.168.0.205/` (Just the scheme and host, no additional `/camera/` path)

If you look at the html you'll see stuff like:

```
<script src="/incl/prototypes.js?ver=5.80.1" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In short, you need to re-write the content you are serving to reflect the new URL you'll be requesting it from: `http://192.168.0.205/camera/`

You can do that using a [sub filter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html):

```
 location /camera {
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass          http://192.168.0.205:80/;
    proxy_redirect      default;

    # nevuh fuhget where you from
    sub_filter_once     off;
    sub_filter_types    *;
    sub_filter          '"/'    '"/camera/';
    sub_filter          '=/'    '=/camera/';
}
```

Depending on your camera, you may have to play around with and add more `sub_filter` lines to catch all of the places where the base path is incorrectly pointing to `/`.  Also, this is basically parsing html/js/cs with REGEX so beware.